# Rails multi-record form only saves parameters for last record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters

I'm trying to offer teachers a form that will create multiple students at once. It seems that most people tackle this concept with nested attributes, but I'm having a hard time understanding how that would work when I'm only using a single model. [This article](http://vicfriedman.github.io/blog/2015/07/18/create-multiple-objects-from-single-form-in-rails/) made it seem possible to achieve this without nested attributes, but my results are not working the way the author suggests. The students array should include one hash for each section of the form. But when I submit the form and check the parameters, only one single hash exists in the array.

Adjusting her approach, I've got this controller:

**students_controller.rb**

```
  def multi
    @student_group = []
    5.times do
      @student_group << Student.new
    end
  end
```

(I'm using an action I've called "multi" because it's a different view than the regular "create" action, which only creates one student at a time. I've tried moving everything into the regular create action, but I get the same results.)

The view:

**multi.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag students_path do %>
  <% @student_group.each do |student| %>
    <%= fields_for 'students[]', student do |s| %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= s.label :first_name %><br>
        <%= s.text_field :first_name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= s.label :last_name %><br>
        <%= s.text_field :last_name %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The results:

```
(byebug) params

<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3Xpi4XeqXuPs9jQvevy+nvGB1HiProddZzWq6Ed7Oljr3TR2fhx9Js6fN/F9xYcpgfDckCBOC2CoN+MrlFU0Bg==", "students"=>{"first_name"=>"fff", "last_name"=>"ggg"}, "commit"=>"Save changes", "controller"=>"students", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

Only one has is included for a student named "fff ggg". There should be four other hashes with different students.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fields_for` is only used in conjunction with `form_for`. The `for` is referring to a model, which it expects you to use. Since you're trying to build a form with no model, you have to construct your own input field names.

Don't use `fields_for` but instead, render each input using the form tag helpers e.g.

```
<%= label_tag "students__first_name", "First Name" %>
<%= text_field_tag "students[][first_name]" %>
```

...and so on.

The key is that the field names have that `[]` in them to indicate that the students parameters will be an array of hashes. You almost got it by telling `fields_for` to be called `students[]` but `fields_for` ignored it because it needs a model to work correctly.

Comment: This worked. Thank you. If you wouldn't mind, I'm unfamiliar with the double underscore syntax. As in, "students__first_name". Do you know what this is called, so I can read more?

Comment: It's simply the way Rails converts the input name of the text field `"students[][first_name]"` into the its id. Using the [sanitize_to_id](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L898) method. Labels should have a `for` attribute that designates which input ID they are for (so that clicking on the label places cursor focus on the input). Therefore, the first argument to `label_tag` is the sanitized id version of the first argument to `text_field_tag` we have to do this because regular form tag helpers don't do it for you.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks again.